Loading views from different class library (RazorFormat)
We wish to be able to load Views from separate class libraries via RazorFormat.
We have tried setting:
Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat()
{
    ViewLocations = paths.ToList(),
});

We have tried loading via EmbeddedResources and loading in an EmbeddedFileProvider.
Is there a way to load in views from a separate class library the the currently executing assembly?

Razor is a complex technology that includes runtime code generation which inhibits its usage as a library making tasks like unit testing or flexible deployment options like this harder than using a clean encapsulated view library like #Script Pages would. ServiceStack.Razor has also been deprecated in favor of using Razor Pages directly in our latest .NET Templates which we recommend new .NET projects use instead.
But we did have a 10 year old .NET Framework project which did this in ServiceStack.Gap, the projects are obsolete but it contains info on the approach used to enable Embedded Razor Resources:
Creating an embedded ServiceStack App
To create the portable version of Benchmarks Analyzer we simply
copied the resources from HttpBenchmarks project
into a new BenchmarksAnalyzer.Resources
project that contains all the websites html/cshtml/js/css/img/etc assets.
All this package does is change all the *.cshtml pages BuildAction to Content and change the web assets to
EmbeddedResource so they all get compiled into the BenchmarksAnalyzer.Resources.dll. It also adds a MS Build task
to BenchmarksAnalyzer.Resources.csproj to get VS.NET to pre-compile the Razor views.
Registering Embedded Resources and Compiled Razor Views to your AppHost
To get ServiceStack to make use of your compiled Razor Views you need to specify the Assembly ServiceStack
should scan when you're registering the RazorFormat, i.e:
Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat {
    LoadFromAssemblies = { typeof(Resources.BaseTypeMarker).Assembly },
});

To tell ServiceStack that it should serve resources embedded inside dlls we just need to add it the HostConfig:
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    EmbeddedResourceBaseTypes = { GetType(), typeof(Resources.BaseTypeMarker) },
});

